# Collectors groupingBy type inference failure

Tags: java, intellij-idea, type-inference

I have a `Map<String, Long>`.

I would like to build a new map based on this of the format `Map<Long, List<String>>`.

It gives the list of strings for a given long value in the first map.

Example:

```
a 1
b 1
c 2

result:
1 [a, b]
2 [c]
```

To get the map keys in sorted order, I'm using a TreeMap. The below code works fine

```
Map<String, Long> originalMap = new HashMap<>();
        //...
TreeMap<Long, List<String>> result = originalMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

If I want the keys to be in descending order, I can use a TreeMap with a Comparator as

```
new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Plugging this into the code, yields

```
TreeMap<Long, List<String>> result = originalMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

My IDE (Intellij) does not **show** any compilation errors. But when I try to run this, it throws compilation errors (does not show any errors in IDE but fails compilation when running).

javac fails compilation too.

```
Main.java:12: error: no suitable method found for groupingBy((e)->e.getValue(),()->new Tr[...]er()),Collector<Object,CAP#1,List<Object>>)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue(), () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
                                   ^
    method Collectors.<T#1,K#1>groupingBy(Function<? super T#1,? extends K#1>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1,K#1
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Collectors.<T#2,K#2,A#1,D#1>groupingBy(Function<? super T#2,? extends K#2>,Collector<? super T#2,A#1,D#1>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2,K#2,A#1,D#1
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Collectors.<T#3,K#3,D#2,A#2,M>groupingBy(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#3>,Supplier<M>,Collector<? super T#3,A#2,D#2>) is not applicable
      (inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: Object
        upper bound(s): Comparable<? super T#4>,T#4,Object)
  where T#1,K#1,T#2,K#2,A#1,D#1,T#3,K#3,D#2,A#2,M,T#4 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,K#1>groupingBy(Function<? super T#1,? extends K#1>)
    K#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1,K#1>groupingBy(Function<? super T#1,? extends K#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,K#2,A#1,D#1>groupingBy(Function<? super T#2,? extends K#2>,Collector<? super T#2,A#1,D#1>)
    K#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,K#2,A#1,D#1>groupingBy(Function<? super T#2,? extends K#2>,Collector<? super T#2,A#1,D#1>)
    A#1 extends Object declared in method <T#2,K#2,A#1,D#1>groupingBy(Function<? super T#2,? extends K#2>,Collector<? super T#2,A#1,D#1>)
    D#1 extends Object declared in method <T#2,K#2,A#1,D#1>groupingBy(Function<? super T#2,? extends K#2>,Collector<? super T#2,A#1,D#1>)
    T#3 extends Object declared in method <T#3,K#3,D#2,A#2,M>groupingBy(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#3>,Supplier<M>,Collector<? super T#3,A#2,D#2>)
    K#3 extends Object declared in method <T#3,K#3,D#2,A#2,M>groupingBy(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#3>,Supplier<M>,Collector<? super T#3,A#2,D#2>)
    D#2 extends Object declared in method <T#3,K#3,D#2,A#2,M>groupingBy(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#3>,Supplier<M>,Collector<? super T#3,A#2,D#2>)
    A#2 extends Object declared in method <T#3,K#3,D#2,A#2,M>groupingBy(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#3>,Supplier<M>,Collector<? super T#3,A#2,D#2>)
    M extends Map<K#3,D#2> declared in method <T#3,K#3,D#2,A#2,M>groupingBy(Function<? super T#3,? extends K#3>,Supplier<M>,Collector<? super T#3,A#2,D#2>)
    T#4 extends Comparable<? super T#4> declared in method <T#4>reverseOrder()
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
Main.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
                        Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getKey(), Collectors.toList())));
                                                 ^
  symbol:   method getKey()
  location: variable e of type Object
2 errors
```

---

To fix this,  I have to add type witness to the `Comparator.reverseOrder` as

```
() -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.<Long>reverseOrder())
```

An interesting point is Intellij shows a warning here as `Explicit type arguments can be inferred` i.e, it indicates there is no need to add the type arguments/witness here.

[image]
**Question:**

1) Does it fail compilation due to a weakness in Java's (complex) type system?

2) Why does Intellij not capture the compilation error? A mismatch between Intellij compiler and javac?

Comment: Those hints about being able to omit the type witness aren't generated by a compiler but by IntelliJ's code inspection. I'm surprised it didn't catch the error when you left it though. In this case the witness is required _somewhere_ I believe, and I do notice that `Comparator`'s static method for `#reverseOrder` actually uses a dangling generic return: `static <T extends Comparator<? super T>> Comparator<T>`. Can't say where without combing over the stack trace but somewhere along the way the inference is lost.

Comment: See dupe for explanation. I've raised an issue on JetBrain's issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-212740

Comment: Thanks @Michael. Didn't realize it was a dupe

Comment: No problem. It wasn't particularly easy to find. I got there via a search for "reverseOrder type witness", in case you're wondering. Good to have signposts anyway. Hopefully your question makes it easier to find for others.